# Looking for an algorithm for moving through a list with math

Tags: algorithm, math

I have a list of numbers. Instead of painting them all in one row I am painting the list in rows of 5.

Now I can select one number and from there move left, right, up or down.

[image]

In this list of 15 numbers (indexed 0 to 14) I have selected index 11, coloured red.

If I move left I have to subtract 1 from the index of my selection. If I move right I add 1. Down means I add 5 and up means I subtract 5.

However, if I go down when I am in the bottom-most row, I want to end up in the first row, as such:

[image]

The math / algorithm for that is simple:

```
index += 5;
if (index > list.size() ) index = index % 5;   // % is modulo

//So, since I start with index 11: (11 + 5) % 5 = 1, which is the index of 01.
```

However, I cannot seem to figure out what to do when I am going from the top-most row up, which takes me to the bottom-most row. (From 01 I would end at 11)

If I have a list of exactly 15 items, then I could simply do:

```
index -= 5;
if (index < 0) index += index.size(); 

//So:  1 - 5 = -4
//    -4 + 15 = 11.
```

But if my list is not divisible by 5, then this does not work.

So I am looking for an algorithm that would solve this problem in all cases, including when the size of a list is not divisble by the length of its rows.

Comment: depending on how your language handles modulus with negative numbers, `index = index % 15` may or may not solve all "index out of range" issues simultaneously.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can probably be optimized further, but here's one approach:

```
var fullRows = list.Length / NUM_COLUMNS; //using integer division
var maxPos = fullRows * NUM_COLUMNS + currentIndex;
return maxPos < list.Length ? maxPos : maxPos - NUM_COLUMNS;
```

What this does is gets the number of full rows then starts by assuming there *is* another row after it. It then checks if that position really exists, and if not it backs off a row to be inside the final full row.

Comment: I had to use nRows instead of nFullRows but it's working smoothly now. Thanks